# Deploy glusterfs/heketi inside Kubernetes 1.6.1 on GKE cos image

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, glusterfs, google-container-os

I am facing this problem when deploying Glusterfs + Heketi (thanks to [this excellent repo](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes)) inside a GKE Kubernetes 1.6.1 cluster with nodes using the cos image. The`gk-deploy` script went well until it tried to execute `heketi-cli -s http://${heketi_service} setup-openshift-heketi-storage`

`` Error: Unable to execute command on glusterfs-xxxxx:   /usr/sbin/modprobe failed: 1
thin: Required device-mapper target(s) not detected in your kernel.
Run `lvcreate --help' for more information.
Failed on setup openshift heketi storage ``

I know the fix that consists in using `modeprobe dm_thin_pool` to each Kubernetes node, But it won't work on the cos image type.

How could we load this module in a google container optimized OS (cos image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heketi make use of this module when creating LVM devices so required in the host image. This module should be part of cos or similar image in GKE as like other distros. It would be appreciated if you can open a RFE request to achieve the same.

Comment: I created [the issue 715009](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715009) on the chrome os project as the cos image is based on it. But I am not sure if this is the best place to ask for this kinf of things. I also sent a comment through my google cloud platform console. Thanks

Comment: This was the right place. Things are moving see comments on the issue I mentioned.

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks  David B